# Como usar setTimeOut en una función asincrona con javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

Estoy tratando de crear una funcion que cada 30 segudos consulte se cerro la sesion en el servidor, y dado el caso de que asi sea abra un modal para volver a iniciar sesión
Este es el código que tengo:

```
const ConsultarSesion = async () => {
    let result = (
        await fetch("/index.aspx/EstadoSesion", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
    ).d

    if (!result.Status) {
        $("#mdlLoginR").modal()
    }

  
    await setTimeout(ConsultarSesion , 30000)
}
$(document).ready(() => {
    ConsultarSesion()
})
```

La cuestion es que una vez detecta la primera vez que la sesión se cerró y abre el modal, despues no lo vuelve a hacer

Answer (score 1):

bueno tienes varios problemas allí con el sync y await, te dejo un ejemplo mas detallado

```js
async function ConsultarSesion() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch("/index.aspx/EstadoSesion", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" }
        });
        if (response.status === 200) {
            let result = await response.json();
            if (!result.Status) {
                $("#mdlLoginR").modal();
            }
        } else {
            // Manejar el error de la respuesta HTTP aquí si es necesario
            console.error("Error al obtener el estado de la sesión");
        }

        // Llamar a ConsultarSesion nuevamente
        setTimeout(ConsultarSesion, 30000);
    } catch (error) {
        // Manejar cualquier error que ocurra durante la ejecución de la función para que no se pierda la reejecucion y sepas que esta sucediendo
        console.error("Error en la función ConsultarSesion:", error);
    }
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    ConsultarSesion();  //llamas al cargar el documento
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

aun que para mi gusto en lugar de mostrar un modal simplemente recargaría la pagina.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por  su colaboración, realmente este es un código reducido del original con lo nescesario para la pregunta. 
Por otro lado noté que tenia un return fuera de la llaves de validación de un if lo cual hacia que no se alcanzara el setimeout

Comment: siempre al usar ajax es bueno usar `try catch` ya que en oportunidades tendrás un resultado inesperado que hara que el código no siga ejecutando

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `setInterval()` en vez de `setTimeout()`. Esta función, a diferencia de la que tú usas permite ejecutar la función que pases como parámetro múltiples veces, en vez de solamente una.

```js
const intervalID = setInterval(consultarSesion, 3000);

function consultarSesion () {
  console.log('Se consulta la sesión')
}
```

**Referencias:** [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: Lo ideal es poder usar async-await, ya que se hace una peticion post al servidor